# Accessing Multiple ids with closely similar names

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a confusion, I have a scenario like this:

```
<div id="min1"></div>
<div id="max1"></div>


<div id="min2"></div>
<div id="max2"></div>
```

I am using this :

```
$("[id^=min]", "[id^=max]").val('hello')
```

to manipulate them. It doesn't work. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `$` to select elements, only pass a *single* selector string as an argument, not multiple different arguments. Separate each different selector by a comma. Also, to set the text of a non-input-like element, use `.text()`, not `.val()`:

```js
$("[id^=min], [id^=max]").text('hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="min1"></div>
<div id="max1"></div>


<div id="min2"></div>
<div id="max2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. I am new to this. Your information was very helpful.